# Can not access api when set up Node.js app with Apache on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, proxy, apache2

I'm deploying my node.js app with apache on ubuntu following `https://imstudio.medium.com/set-up-a-node-js-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04-e0323c333c20`.

This node.js app is listening on port 4000. I put it in directory`/var/www/html/api` and start it by pm2.

After deployment, I tested my api and found that only my home url `www.myweb.tk/api` works, and other sub urls, for example`www.myweb.tk/api/location`, does not work.

Here is my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweb.tk
    ServerAlias www.myweb.tk

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <Location /api>
        ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:4000/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://127.0.0.1:4000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell me how to make other urls works? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I has same issue, but with *nginx*, i solved it by adding `/api` to proxy

Try to pass `http://127.0.0.1:4000/api`

---

**UPD:**

Or search for something like `request url` varible in Apache

Comment: Thank you, Levaya. I tried it but still have this issue.

Comment: try to http://localhost:4000 instead http://127.0.0.1:4000, and also try with `api`

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by remove "/" behind 4000 in proxy.